# vim powerline plugin doesn't work under ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, vim, pathogen, vim-powerline

guys i installed the vim_powerline plugin through pathogen which am not sure works, my ~/.vimrc looks like this:

```
"pathogen
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags() 

filetype plugin indent on

set laststatus=2
let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'
set encoding=utf-8
set t_Co=256
set fillchars+=stl:\ ,stlnc:\
let g:Powerline_mode_V="V·LINE"
let g:Powerline_mode_cv="V·BLOCK"
let g:Powerline_mode_S="S·LINE"
let g:Powerline_mode_cs="S·BLOCK"
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

set nocp
set nocompatible
set number
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab


autocmd Filetype python set tabstop=2
autocmd Filetype python set shiftwidth=2
autocmd Filetype python set softtabstop=2
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete


if has("gui_running")
        colorscheme evening
        set co=180
        set gfn=Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono\ 9
endif


" All system-wide defaults are set in $VIMRUNTIME/debian.vim and sourced by
" the call to :runtime you can find below.  If you wish to change any of those
" settings, you should do it in this file (/etc/vim/vimrc), since debian.vim
" will be overwritten everytime an upgrade of the vim packages is performed.
" It is recommended to make changes after sourcing debian.vim since it alters
" the value of the 'compatible' option.

" This line should not be removed as it ensures that various options are
" properly set to work with the Vim-related packages available in Debian.
runtime! debian.vim

" Uncomment the next line to make Vim more Vi-compatible
" NOTE: debian.vim sets 'nocompatible'.  Setting 'compatible' changes numerous
" options, so any other options should be set AFTER setting 'compatible'.
"set compatible

" Vim5 and later versions support syntax highlighting. Uncommenting the next
" line enables syntax highlighting by default.
if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif

" If using a dark background within the editing area and syntax highlighting
" turn on this option as well
"set background=dark

" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
"if has("autocmd")
"  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
"endif

" Uncomment the following to have Vim load indentation rules and plugins
" according to the detected filetype.
"if has("autocmd")
"  filetype plugin indent on
"endif

" The following are commented out as they cause vim to behave a lot
" differently from regular Vi. They are highly recommended though.
"set showcmd        " Show (partial) command in status line.
"set showmatch      " Show matching brackets.
"set ignorecase     " Do case insensitive matching
"set smartcase      " Do smart case matching
"set incsearch      " Incremental search
"set autowrite      " Automatically save before commands like :next and :make
"set hidden     " Hide buffers when they are abandoned
"set mouse=a        " Enable mouse usage (all modes)

" Source a global configuration file if available
if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif
```

but still i only get a white status bar when launching vim and also when I type :scriptnames  all I get is this:

```
1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
6: /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
7: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/nosyntax.vim
8: ~/.vimrc
9: ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
10: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftoff.vim
11: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
12: /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
13: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
14: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
15: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
16: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
17: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
18: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
19: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
20: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
21: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
22: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

as you can see there is no powerline and in the ~/vim/bundle I got the folder vim-powerline inside so i don't really know wtf is going on here i installed the fonts and all :(

Comment: Show us the rest of your `~/.vimrc`, please.

Comment: @romainl here you go i edited the post and thanks for helping out :)

Comment: You should remove everything after line 36 and start another session.

Comment: @romainl thank so much no there's only one more thing it's showing all in wired symbols i think i have to set it to use the powerline font somehow o_O?

Comment: @romainl ok i figured it out by myself it seems that if i want to use the fancy symbols i need to install the patched fonts so i just changed this let g:Powerline_symbols = 'unicode' and it's working :)